# How to conditionally show/hide toolbar buttons in Fyne?

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

I'm trying to let users record audio. I want a 'record' button when they aren't recording, and when they are recording to change it to a 'stop recording' button. Furthermore, I expected this to work, but both buttons always show on the toolbar:

```
var startRecording, stopRecordingFunc func()

recordButton := widget.NewToolbarAction(theme.MediaRecordIcon(), startRecording)
stopButton := widget.NewToolbarAction(theme.MediaStopIcon(), stopRecordingFunc)

startRecording = func() {
    if !recording {
        recording = true
        stopRecording = make(chan struct{})
        recordWg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            recordAudio("output.wav", stopRecording, &recordWg)
            recording = false
            recordButton.ToolbarObject().Show()
            stopButton.ToolbarObject().Hide()
        }()
        recordButton.ToolbarObject().Hide()
        stopButton.ToolbarObject().Show()
    }
}

stopRecordingFunc = func() {
    if recording {
        close(stopRecording)
        recordWg.Wait()
        recording = false
        recordButton.ToolbarObject().Show()
        stopButton.ToolbarObject().Hide()
    }
}

recordButton.OnActivated = startRecording
stopButton.OnActivated = stopRecordingFunc

toolbar := widget.NewToolbar(recordButton, stopButton)
stopButton.ToolbarObject().Hide()
```

I've tried adding calls to `Refresh()` but it makes no difference.

How can I conditionally show/hide toolbar buttons?

Comment: Please post updated (working) code based on the hints (accepted answer) from @andy.xyz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `.ToolbarObject()` it is creating a new instance - which is not in the toolbar at all.
To manipulate the contents of a toolbar you need to use the toolbar APIs, or those exposed directly on the `ToolbarAction`.

From your code it looks like what you would be best using is `SetIcon` to change the appearance.

Comment: That's great thanks. I have to call `toolbar.Refresh()` after `SetIcon` to make it actually show the new icon.